# Approval Process: Allow User A to Reject subject to override by User B

Tags: approval-process

I need to create a approval process where I will have two approver.. Approver A and approver B. **The requirement is even if approver A rejects the approval process , it should go the approver B.**  Approver B can change the Approver A decision and aprrover the records.

Whats the best way to do it ?

Comment: welcome to SFSE; you'll get best results here if you demonstrate you have tried some options. The tools at your disposal are approval process entry criteria; approval process field update actions, and apex

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of multi step approval process.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_useful_approval_processes_jobs.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @ Thanks . but question is how the process goes to second approver even if first rejected. what i know, once the process rejected it goes to final rejection action . I want the process to be submitted to next apporver even if it rejected .